# What situations warrant using Action<T> as a parameter?

Tags: c#

I know that using Action as a method parameter will allow to use lambdas with that method, but what kinds of situations would come up where I would need to use that (or want to use that) in LOB applications/web applications? I believe that LINQ uses it heavily, but I just can't see how I could use it in my own code without making things awkward or unnecessarily complex.

Does the need to use Action as a method parameter arise often and I just can't see it (yet) or is it something that is rarely used in LOB applications?

Comment: Look at the TPL and methods in the [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) class.  Sometimes you just need a delegate that does something but doesn't necessarily return anything.

Comment: I can't see any mention in the quesion of Func so I don't think the OP is concerned with the question of whether Action returns or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example is if you have a long-running operation and you want to provide progress feedback to the user:

```
void LongRunningOperation(Action<float> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lotsOfIterations; ++i)
    {
        SlowCalculation();
        progress(((float)i / lotsOfIterations) * 100);
    }
}
```

Of course, you could also do this using events but this way it is easy to see that the callback relates to this method. If you had a large class you may not want to add another event just for a single method.

Another example might be if you want to allow the caller to mutate each value of an operation. For this you'd use Func<> which is analogous to Action but returns a value:

```
void Operation(Func<int, int> mutate)
{
    for (int i in someCollection)
    {
        i = mutate(i);
        SomeCalculation(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Action is just a delegate that return void.

You can use it in many place where you want to delegate the execution of the code.

I think an easy example is if you have a list that you want to display all data of it.

You could wrote

```
for(...)
{
    Console.WriteLine(...);
}
```

But with Action, method like ForEach take this delegate as parameter and let you do :

```
myList.ForEach(s=>Console.WriteLine(s));
```

In fact, the ForEach use the Action as parameter that let you reference to a delegate method:

```
public void Each<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
        action(item);
}
```

So, the Action could be not Linq but simply a pointer to a method that return void and that take as parameter something of T type.

```
    List<string> myList= new List<string>(){ "ABC", "DEF", "H" };
    myList.ForEach(Print);
    public void Print(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

This also work.

Comment: Fixed, oops typed too fast ;) Thanks @KirkWoll

Comment: Actually your successive edits were both legal, and actually a good demonstration of a subtle point.  i.e.  `myList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)` and `myList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s))` are both valid, the latter involving an extra indirection (though easier to read to my eyes).

Answer (score 2):

Use it wherever you have a simple action to perform that has no return value.

Logging is a good example.

Comment: Would you mind providing some sort of sample code? I'm just having a hard time imagining what the code would look like for that example.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question.